# how to run mongo db query via python script?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have two mongo db query

first is:

```
 db.sale_order.find().forEach(function(doc){doc.orderDate = new 
        Date(doc.orderDate);db.sale_order.save(doc);})
```

and second is:

```
db.sale_order.aggregate({$group: { _id: {year : { $year : "$orderDate" }, month : {$month : "$orderDate"},day :{ $dayOfMonth : "$orderDate"},},price : {$sum: "$price"}}} )
```

this second query is only work after running first query , after that performing other operation using python .

so running this two query , I am using following code :

```
def create_demo_accounts():
    Account.objects.all().delete()
    client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    db = client['mydb']
    collection = db['sale_order']

    #collection.find().forEach(function(doc){doc.orderDate = new Date(doc.orderDate);db.sale_order.save(doc);})
    for doc in collection.find():
      doc['orderDate'] = Date(doc['orderDate'])  # line 127
      db.sale_order.save(doc) 
    try:
        for post in collection.aggregate({$group: { _id: {year : { $year : "$orderDate" }, month : {$month : "$orderDate"},day :{ $dayOfMonth : "$orderDate"},},price : {$sum: "$price"}}} ):   # line 130
          oid = post['_id']
          try:
            year = post['year']
            month = post['month']
            day = post['dayOfMonth']
            price = post['price']
            Account.objects.create(days = day, sales=price,
                                 expenses=400, ceo="Welch")
          except:
            pass
    except:
      pass
```

then it is giving following error :

```
SyntaxError at /
invalid syntax (utils.py, line 130)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.8.4
Exception Type: SyntaxError
Exception Value:    
invalid syntax (utils.py, line 130)
Exception Location: /home/shubham/Music/Progress/django-graphos-master/demo_project/demo/views.py in <module>, line 12
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/shubham/Music/Progress/django-graphos-master/demo_project',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mango-0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_mongo_auth-0.1.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_mongoengine-0.1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_graphos-0.0.2a0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
Server time:    Mon, 21 Sep 2015 12:26:15 +0530
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pymongo's `db.eval` function.
e.g. your query:

```
db.getCollection('test').update({filter},{update})
```

using pymongo you can do like:

```
db.eval("db.getCollection('test').update({filter},{update})")
```

Comment: `db.eval` was deprecated.  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.eval/

Answer (score 0):

You need to **use quotes** when specifying `pipeline` and `options` in [`collection.aggregate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db-collection-aggregate) call:

```
collection.aggregate({'$group': { '_id': {'year' : { '$year' : "$orderDate" }, 'month' : {'$month' : "$orderDate"},'day' :{ '$dayOfMonth' : "$orderDate"},},'price' : {'$sum': "$price"}}})
```

Also, you **can't directly use mongodb `Date` constructor in python**. You can instead **use [`bson.Code`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/code.html)** to pass the javascript code in Python .

```
import bson # import bson library
# pass the javascript code string in bson 'Code' object
collection.find().forEach(bson.Code("function(doc){doc.orderDate = new Date(doc.orderDate);db.sale_order.save(doc);}"))
```

Comment: ya its work, but again have error on line 127  **global name 'Date' is not defined**

Comment: You can use `bson.Code` to pass the javascript function to `.forEach()` in your script. updated the ans.